# Regular Expression to stop at specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following javascript to return an array containing the first 2 numerical values found in string

```
text.match(/(\d+)/g);
```

How can I stop the search if an open bracket is found and instead return either NaN or zero?
For example:

- **10-20 bags (+£1.50)** would return 10 and 20
- **20+ bags (+£1.00)** would return 20

Comment: If you're trying to match `X-Y`, then match that, rather than matching both numbers separately. What exactly are you trying to match? There is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lookahead in your regex in order to match all the numbers before the first `(`,

```
\d+(?=[^()]*\()
```

**Example:**

```
> "10-20 bags (+£1.50)".match(/\d+(?=[^()]*\()/g);
[ '10', '20' ]
> "20+ bags (+£1.00)".match(/\d+(?=[^()]*\()/g);
[ '20' ]
```

Comment: That will only work if every line against which the regex is matched contains a `(`.  It will fail, too, if there are additional digits and a second `(` following the first `(`.  Those may be acceptable limitations, but it's not what @aduch actually asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex using lookahead:

```
/(\d+)(?=.*\()/
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cL3rI3/2)

Here `(?=.*\()` is called lookahead that makes sure match `\d+` if it is not followed by an opening `(`.

Comment: What if the data contains multiple or no `(`?

Comment: I think it is better to know from OP what the requirements are around that possibility.

Comment: @NickW: Can you clarify your requirement for multiple `(` or no `(`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the full generality you requested -- that is, if the lines being matched don't necessarily contain exactly one `(` -- then I think the only solution is to first match the lead text before any parenthesis (i.e. `/^([^(]*)/`) and then select your digit strings from that.

Javascript regexes do not support lookbehind, which is what you need to do the job in the full generality you specified with a single regex.

Comment: Yes there will be cases where no ( exists, so I've had to check for the presence of ( with indexOf and if it exists then remove it and all characters that follow and then use the following regex that I had previously used on the remaining string: text.match(/(\d+)/g);